# Netty is giving me a wrong port using TCP

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I'm using Netty with Java trying to configure a TCP client. Everything is working so far, except that I'm connecting on port 1050 but when I call messageEvent.getRemoteAddress() on messageReceived() method of the handler, I'm getting the port 1500. I changed the port to 1049 but I'm still receiving 1500. This is Netty's problem or can it be the server's problem?

My hardware setup here is: this netty client running on a Java server, and several access control equipments spread through the area here. The equipments act as tcp servers and the netty as the client, that process everything the server sends and just reply to them.

The tcp server initialization is this:

```
private ChannelFactory fabrica;
private ServerBootstrap bootstrap;

public void iniciarServidorTCP() {
    fabrica = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(fabrica);
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast("decoderDeMensagem", new MensagemDecoderTCP());
            pipeline.addLast("handlerGerente", new GerenteTCP());
            pipeline.addLast("encoder de mensagem", new MensagemEncoderTCP());
            return pipeline;
        }
    });
    bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("child.reuseAddress", true);
    bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(1050));
}
```

Any idea why I'm getting 1500 instead of 1050? Could it be a problem with the equipment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every TCP connection has a source port and a destination port. When you connect to a server, the server sees the destination port as its well-known address. The client picks the source port. On either end, getting the "remote address" gets the other side's address. So when you call get remote address on the server, you get the *client*'s address, not the server's.

Imagine you have a server with one IP address and one well-known port. Now, say you have a client machine with one IP address. If it make's four connections to the server, how can either end tell those connections apart? The answer is that the *client* port is different.

Comment: Well, yeah, I know that, it's supposed to be that way, the problem is that it's not being that way. Both server and client are configured with port 1050, yet I'm receiving 1500 somehow, that's what I want to know why

Comment: The client binds to port 1050? Did you test to make sure that bind succeeds? (And if you knew that, why did you paste all code that's irrelevant? How the server sets its port has nothing to do with the issue which involves how the client sets its port and how the server determines the client port.)

Comment: The bind succeeds because I'm able to communicate with the equipments, and yes, the client binds to port 1050, or else it won't receive data from the server. And I pasted the code because of my limited knowledge in this area, so I figured it could be because of some wrong configuration at startup. I'll do a few more tests to make sure the binding is right, if it is, I really won't know what is wrong with it, because in this same project I also have UDP connection, using almost the same settings, and the port binding is flawless.

Comment: Communication would work fine even if the client's bind failed. The TCP stack would just pick a client port. The code you pasted deals solely with the server port and your issue is with the client port, so the code isn't helpful. Most likely, you either don't bind in the client or the client's bind fails, so the client picks a random port. (Incidentally, why do you care? It's much easier and safer to let the client use a random source port.)

Comment: Actually, the server part is on the equipment, it's not even Java, the code is for the client part, that actually runs on a java server